# How to check session.modifed = True in response object in Django test?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-testing

[django 1.4, python 2.7]

We have a custom session engine that stores session to redis (Pretty much the same as db session engine, just stores in redis).

There are some public endpoints that the session middleware stores a session to redis every time it is invoked (session.modified is set to True), which is not our intention.

I am trying to write unit tests to check which endpoints do generate session.

```
# This endpoint would always save session to redis
def test_endpoint(request, **kwargs):
    request.session['asdfsaf'] = 1
    # Or, request.session.modified = True (Both fine)
    return httplib.OK, "good"
```

### Attempt 1:

```
    response = self.client.post(reverse('test_endpoint', kwargs=self.kwargs), data={...})

    print(response.status_code, response.content) # Ok 
    print('am i modified?', self.client.session.modified) # False

    for i in range(10):
        redis = get_redis_instance(db=i)
        print("redis key", i, redis.keys())  # All return empty redis
```

This unit test is unable to detect a session is saved via django session middleware.
probably due to the fact that a ***new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed*** (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#persistent-state)

### Attempt 2:

Taking inspiration from SessionMiddlewareTests:

```
    request = RequestFactory().post(reverse('test_endpoint', kwargs=self.kwargs), data={...})
    response = HttpResponse('Session test')
    middleware = SessionMiddleware()

    middleware.process_request(request)

    # Handle the response through the middleware
    response = middleware.process_response(request, response)
    print('am i modified', request.session.modified) # False

    for i in range(10):
        redis = get_redis_instance(db=i)
        print("redis key", i, redis.keys())  # All return empty redis
```

Again, I am unable to detect this endpoint is in fact storing session to redis.

How can I programmatically check whether an API creating a session? (that somehow creates it via setting session.modified flag True)?

Last thing I want to do is to test manually and checking redis db myself. (Over 200 public end points and unable to prevent similar issue happening in future).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why not to check `self.client.session`?

Comment: @PawełKordowski, I did that in attempt 1. And that doesn't work as you can see from the official documentation : "new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed", so it would reset session.modified flag.